# How to pop view controller and trigger function

Tags: swift, storyboard

I have 2 view controllers:

- Login screen
- Forgot password screen

When finishing the "forgot password" thing and clicking "send reset link" the view controller should pop and show an alert/a message.

**QUESTION**

How do I `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` and after that show success alert message in the new view controller? I've no idea how I can do that so no code to show at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution "out of the box" here as there is no way to give an auto-completion block to the method. However we can do it with different solution (some are boilerplate, some are short).

1 - **(Simplest and quickest)** You can leverage the fact that popViewController has animation and therefore you can use CATransaction to do something at the end.

```
CATransaction.begin()
navigationController?.popToViewController(self, animated: true)
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({ [weak self] in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    and do here your stuff
})
CATransaction.commit()
```

2 - ***My PREFERED SOLUTION*** will be to create a custom Navigation Controller and pass it a completion block. Then you override the PopToViewController method and you execute your completion. It gives **clarity** and it is **reusable**

```
public class NavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
    private var completion: (() -> Void)?

    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public override func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
    {
        if self.completion != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.completion?()
                self.completion = nil
            })
        }
    }
    

 func popViewController(animated: Bool, completion: @escaping () -> Void) -> UIViewController?
    {
        self.completion = completion
        return super.popViewController(animated: animated)
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate mechanism.Create a variable `alertDelegate` inside the Forgot password view controller.

Set that to Login screen View controller before the forgot password VC is pushed into the navigation controller like `forgotPasswordViewController. alertDelegate = self`

Now override the `didMoveToParentViewController` method in the `ForgotPasswordViewController` and call the delegate function to show the alert.

```
protocol AlertDelegate {
   func showAlert()
}

// inside LoginViewController
extension LoginViewController : AlertDelegate {
   func showAlert() {
         // code to show the alert comes here
   }
}

// before pushing the ForgotPasswordViewController
forgotPasswordViewController.alertDelegate = self

// inside ForgotPasswordViewController
alertDelegate: AlertDelegate?

override func didMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    if parent == nil { // When the viewController is popped from the navigation controller the parent will be nil.
       alertDelegate?.showAlert()
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error:
Instance member 'alertDelegate' cannot be used on type 'ViewControllerForgotPassword'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

In this row: 
ViewControllerForgotPassword.alertDelegate = self

Comment: Yeah. forgotPasswordViewController is an instance of ForgotPasswordViewController. You have to use it on an instance variable. I have edited my answer for more clarity.

Comment: Can you share the implementation and the error you got? Also kindly check if the 'self' in forgotPasswordViewController.alertDelegate = self line refers to the LoginViewController instance and the showAlert() function is called when the ForgotPasswordVC is popped